# Is there an equivalent of the MySQL show columns statement in c# / .net?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'd like to programmatically get the properties of all columns in a table in a MySQL database. Specifically I'm looking to find if a column is nullable or not so required items can be identified in the user interface written in C# / WPF.

I am using MySqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command) to identify the columns required in a particular stored procedure. [MySqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters is not supported](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/Methods_T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommandBuilder.htm), and [MySQL does not support making parameters to a stored procedure optional](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15975). Parameter.IsNullable always returns false in the list of parameters returned by DeriveParameters.

This is one of the tables in the database:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pacswlibinvtool`.`authorstab`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pacswlibinvtool`.`authorstab` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pacswlibinvtool`.`authorstab` (
    `idAuthors` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `LastName` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `FirstName` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `MiddleName` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `YearOfBirth` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `YearOfDeath` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idAuthors`, `LastName`, `FirstName`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `idAuthors_UNIQUE` (`idAuthors` ASC),
    INDEX `LastName` (`LastName` ASC),
    INDEX `LastCMFirst` (`LastName` ASC, `FirstName` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = UTF8MB4;
```

I'd like to be able to identify the columns that can be null in a c# application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the standard [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema).COLUMNS to explore the properties of your columns

```
string cmdText = @"SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                   WHERE Table_Name = 'authorstab'";
using(MySqlConnection cnn = GetMySqlConnection())
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cnn))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cnn.Open();
    using(MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        dt.Load(reader);
}
```

Now the DataTable *dt* is filled with rows that contains, each row, all the info about every column of your table including also a column named IS_NULLABLE of type boolean

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code -

```
    cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True");
        cn.Open();
         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COLUMN_NAME,IS_NULLABLE FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'My_Test_Table' ", cn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

           while( reader.Read())
           {

                string str1="Column name is   "+ reader.GetString(0) + "  Null Allowed : - " + reader.GetString(1); 
                MessageBox.Show(str1);

            }
        }
```